# Table gets shifted when using threeparttable

Tags: tables, threeparttable

Hello I'm trying to use the threeparttable option but as soon as I do so my table gets shifted and is plotted at the left side of my page.. How can leave the table at the center of the page?
Thanks a lot for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRlXE.png)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{table}[!ht]
 \begin{threeparttable} 
 \footnotesize \centering 

  \caption[Parámetros físicos evaluados en el análisis de sensibilidad]{Parámetros físicos evaluados en el análisis de sensibilidad y coeficiente de variación CV ($\sqrt{\mathrm{MSE}}/\bar{O}$) para las variables $T_{m02}$, $H_s^{(ss)}$, $H_s^{(ig)}$, $R_s^{(ss)}$ y $R_s^{(ig)}$ del caso C15.} 
        \label{tab:sensibilidad_parametros_caso15} 
        \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|rrrrr} \toprule Run         & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Parameters Hydrodynamics} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parameters Morphodynmics}                  \\
                            & $Eq.$   & $k\textsubscript{str}\,\mathrm{[m^{-1/3}s]}$ & $\nu\,\mathrm{[mPa]}$ & BL\textsubscript{f} & SE\textsubscript{f} \\ \midrule  Eq.1 & FE & 84     & 1.0      &  MPM        &   $\beta_{KF}$
                =1.3 \\

                 Eq.2  & FV & 84     & 1.0      &  MPM   &   $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3         \\  \midrule  $k_{str}.1$  & FV & 84    & 1.0      &  MPM   & $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3          \\

                 $k_{str}.2$  & FV & 104     & 1.0      &  MPM   &  $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3  \\   $k_{str}.3$   & FV& 64     & 1.0      &  MPM   &  $\beta_{KF}$
                =1.3   \\ \midrule  turb  & FV & 84     & 1.56      &  MPM   & $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3          \\  \midrule  load1  & FV & 84     & 1.0    & MPM   & $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3                 \\   load2  & FV & 84     & 1.0      & V.R   & $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3                 \\   \midrule
                    S1.1  & FV & 84     & 1.0      & MPM   & $\beta_{KF}$ =1.3                 \\
                    S1.2  & FV & 84     & 1.0      & MPM   & $\beta_{KF}$ =3.5                 \\
                    S2.1  & FV & 84     & 1.0      & MPM   & $\phi_{Soulsby}$=36.2$^{\circ}$                   \\
                    S2.2  & FV & 104     & 1.0      & MPM   & $\phi_{Soulsby}$=36.2$^{\circ}$                   \\     \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
    \begin{tablenotes} 
    \item \textit{Note: $\phi$ = Sediment intensity;}  
    \end{tablenotes} 
    \end{threeparttable} 
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This might sound rude, but the second sentence from `threeparttable`'s documentation explains what happens: “The title and
notes are given a width equal to the body of the table (a tabular environment).” You need to center not only the tabular, but also (or maybe only) the threeparttable, as @MichaelPalmer said below.

Comment: move the `\centering` to below `\begin{table}` but above `\begin{threeparttable}`.

Comment: yes that was it.. I guess I couldn't see the problem from looking to often at it! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AliceM. Could you write an answer, please?